# PHP foreach only returning 1st attribute value of Magento multiselect on product page

Tags: php, magento, foreach, entity-attribute-value

Title pretty much says it all.  I'm trying to output a static block with the same ID as the attribute value, however my code is only outputing the FIRST attribute value.

The following code is in view.phtml and is outputing the first static block of the 5 multiselect values selected.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
<?php
   $cmsstatic = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('collection1')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
   $blockids = explode(",", $cmsstatic);
   foreach($blockids as $kry=>$value)
   {
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($value)->tohtml();

   }
?>
```

Comment: try `print_r($blockids)` to see how many items are in it. might help

Comment: I know there are multiple values selected.

Comment: Please add what it does display in your question, then, because from the too short code you give us, there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: I'm sorry, it displays the first static block.   So the first attribute value properly displays the static block, however any other values in the loop do not display their value.

Comment: I mean, what does `print_r($blockids)` displays...

Comment: I appologize ... It displays Array ( [0] => collection3 [1] => collection6 )

Comment: `setBlockID` maybe without the typo on `Id` -> `setBlockId`?

Comment: Still only one value.

Comment: Should work then, unless your block Identifier does not match the ones you created in the admin, or are not selected for the store you are currently browsing your magento in

Comment: Yeah, I checked to ensure the block IDs were correct and they all totally are.  I thought maybe it was something related to the PHP foreach function?

Comment: There is certainly something stopping it after it gets the first value.  I can change the multiselect value on the product page in the admin to collection2,collection4,collection5 for example and it will return only 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your `$value` block IDs are wrong. Take a look at the output from `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('collection1')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)` and you will probably notice it actually looks something like this: `collection3, collection6`. Notice the spaces after the commas. When you run `explode(",", $cmsstatic)` you are getting the spaces in your resulting array. Since the first block ID contains no extra spaces, it is valid, but none of the following ones will be.

### Solution 1

```
explode(", ", $cmsstatic)
```

### Solution 2

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(trim($value))->toHtml()
```

Comment: Oh, dude thank you so much.  That explanation makes so much sense and works like a charm!